# How to align my second column in footer to bottom?

Tags: html, css, alignment, footer

I have a 2 column footer and in my second I have less content so I want it aligned to bottom. Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/uga8L/

I have tried `vertical-align: bottom;` but nothing works.

This is my html footer

```
<footer id="footer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div id="column_1">
            <ul>

            <li><a href="http://ec.europa.eu/index_ro.htm">Comisia europeană</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://ec.europa.eu/enterprise/sectors/electrical/index_ro.htm">Inginerie electrică</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://ec.europa.eu/enterprise/sectors/rtte/index_ro.htm">Echipamente radio şi echipamente terminale de telecomunicaţii (R&TTE)</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://ec.europa.eu/enterprise/policies/single-market-goods/cemarking/professionals/manufacturers/directives/index_ro.htm?filter=14">Instrumente de masură</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://ec.europa.eu/enterprise/policies/single-market-goods/cemarking/professionals/manufacturers/directives/index_ro.htm?filter=12">Joasă tensiune</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="column_2">
            <ul>
            <li id="footer_logo"><img src="themes/default/images/CE.png"></a></li>
            <li>Aplicarea marcajului european pentru</li>
            <li>compatibilitate electromagnetică - EMC</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Instead of linking directly to your website, please post the relevant CSS and HTML into the question directly (you have posted the HTML, so good job on that part).  Also, providing a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) will be helpful, as they will last longer as opposed to your site, which can disappear at any time.

Comment: ... so could jsFiddle.net. By all means create one, but include the relevant code here, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/uga8L/1/

A main issue is you're not floating the second column here. You can use display:inline-block to use the vertically align element.

```
#column_1, #column_2 {
    display:inline-block;
}
#column_2 {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```